# non greedy regex to select everything between curly braces but not the starting and ending curly braces

Tags: regex, regex-greedy, regex-group

I need a greedy regex to select everything between curly braces but not the starting and ending curly braces 
for example:

{here {first} and {second} and {third}}

output should be 
`{first}`,
`{second}` 
`{third}`

Comment: Where is your question and efforts?

Answer (score 2):

`{[^{]+?}` would work for your test case. However, this won't support arbitrary nesting, which is not possible with regex. If that's what you're looking for, you'll need a parser.

Example: https://regex101.com/r/GrqGdS/1

Edit:

if `{` is written at places where the cardinality operator cannot occur, there is no need to escape it.

Comment: No need to escape everything, [**`{[^{}]+}`**](https://regex101.com/r/WvOzaV/1/) works as expected and is more readable.

Comment: You're right, thanks!